# How to receive menu item events in the document window controller of a document-based app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller, nsmenu

My document document-based app has an AppDelegate, a Document, and a DocumentWindowController.

Inside the DocumentWindowController I want to handle menu events.

MainMenu.xib's File's Owner is the AppDelegate. There is no object representing the "active document's window controller". So I must hook up a menu item action with an IBAction in the App Delegate.

From there, how do I fetch the currently active document and its associated DocumentWindowController so I can forward it the menu events?

Was thinking of sending notifications but this means every document's DocumentWindowController would receive them.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what I was looking for is the "First Responder". Create a connection with this one, not the AppDelegate (File's Owner). Now whoever is first to respond to that action receives it.